# How to get rid of datasource auto configuration for spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I added spring jpa starter dependency in pom, and then remove it. But spring now keeps performing auto-configuration for data source, and hence application doesn't start.

How to get rid of this?

One solution is to have following annotation in application class:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
```

I want to achieve it without doing this.

Comment: can u put all the dependencies u have in pom. springboot's auto configuration depends on that

Comment: can you add logging.level.org.springframework = debug to your application.properties and see what cause that spring still auto configuring data source via configuration report. 
If you check DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class that has @ConditionalClass({DataSource.class , EmbeddedDatabaseType.class}) annotation which is mean one of DataSource.class or Embedded Db that in your classpath still trick auto configuration

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to disable autoconfiguration will be to use property `spring.autoconfigure.exclude` and specify the full path to autoconfiguration class:

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, 
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration
```

Or as you alredy mentioned you can use annotations:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
    DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, 
    DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class    
})
```